# Simple 2D Unity Game has periodical jerkiness

Tags: unity-game-engine, render

I've made a simple 2D game in Unity using the application Tiled for the tilemap, but when I run it, every now and then the screen will jump like it has a quick fps drop.

I'm not sure what would be hurting the performance of the game, because it is not performing any demanding tasks. My only guess is that it could be the large tilemap I'm using, but I feel this is not the problem because the game was still jerky when the map was not large. Furthermore, I tried scaling the map to an even larger size but it didn't make the performance any worse than it already was.

Does anyone know what could be causing the performance issue here? Thanks.

Comment: Explain the "jump" better.

Comment: I think a tutorial I once saw covered this. It has to do with in what resolution the map is rendered, versus the actual resolution of the map. There is an option that needs to be toggled somewhere. But look up unity tuts for Tiled maps, good ones will surely cover this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Periodic frame-rate drops could be caused by a number of things - fortunately Unity gives you a very good tool to track this down in the form of the Profiler (Window > Profiler). It's recommended that you build the game (check `Development Build` and `Autoconnect Profiler`) rather than testing in the editor, as often the editor creates a lot of overhead that shows up in the Profiler and may lead you astray.

Play the game and see if there are any spikes when you notice the fps drop. I would not be surprised if you have Garbage Collection (GC) causing your periodic fps drops. GC is triggered periodically in the background to clean up memory that was allocated but is no longer needed. You can get a good idea of how much memory is being allocated by selecting `CPU Usage` and looking at the `GC Alloc` column. This can add up quickly! Optimising a game to avoid GC spikes is a whole topic unto itself.

But, of course, you problem might have nothing to do with GC spikes. Hopefully the Profiler will tell you which stones you should be turning over.